# When to use F#'s typedefof<'T> vs. typeof<'T>?

Tags: f#

Can someone clarify when to use [typedefof<'T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/operators.typedefof%5B't%5D-type-function-%5Bfsharp%5D) vs. [typeof<'T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/operators.typeof%5B't%5D-type-function-%5Bfsharp%5D)?

Both `typedefof<System.String>` and `typeof<System.String>` return the same `Type` instance.

However, they return different instances and different information for `System.Collections.Generic.List<_>`.

Can I think of `typedefof` as a new and improved `typeof`? Should I just switch to always using `typedefof`? Or is it more subtle than that?

Comment: As the documentation indicates, `typeof` returns the actual type indicated, while `typedefof<'T>` returns the underlying generic type of `'T` if `'T` is generic. So I don't think it's a matter of always using one or the other; it's a matter of which you need in the current situation.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This ought to illustrate the difference.  When you use `typeof`, the compiler infers type arguments and constructs a concrete type.  In this case, the inferred type argument is `System.Object`:

```
let t1 = typeof<System.Collections.Generic.List<_>>
let t2 = typedefof<System.Collections.Generic.List<_>>

printfn "t1 is %s" t1.FullName
printfn "t2 is %s" t2.FullName
```

Output:

```
t1 is System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Object, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]
t2 is System.Collections.Generic.List`1
```

Because `typeof` can only return a constructed type, `typedefof` is necessary if you need a type object representing a generic type definition.

Answer (score 15):

`typeof` is used when you want to get the `System.Type` object for a given type.  `typedefof` is used when you want to get the `System.Type` that represents the type definition for a generic type.  As an example that uses both, suppose you had a type called `Generic<'a>`, and you wanted to create a function that returned the `System.Type` object for the `Generic` of any given type.

```
type Generic<'a> = Value of 'a

let makeGenericOf<'a> () = 
    typedefof<Generic<_>>.MakeGenericType(typeof<'a>)
```

Here, you would use the `typedefof` function to get the type defintion, and `typeof` to get the type of `'a` for constructing the generic `Generic<'a>` `Type`.

Answer (score 7):

I really appreciate the answers from phoog, Aaron, and JLRishe. Here is what I have learned, based on their answers and my own experimentation.

There are two `Type` instances associated with generics.

1. There is a `Type` associated with a generic that has specific type parameters. For example, there is a `Type` associated with `List<int>` and a different `Type` associated with `List<string>`. This is what you get when you use `typeof<>`.

   ```
   > typeof<List<string>>.ToString();;
   val it : string = "Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpList`1[System.String]"

   > typeof<List<int>>.ToString();;
   val it : string = "Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpList`1[System.Int32]"
   ```
2. There is a `Type` associated with the generic type definition itself. For example, there is a single `Type` associated with `List<'T>`, which is the same for `List<int>`, `List<string>`, and `List<_>`. This is what you get when you use `typedefof<>`.

   ```
   > typedefof<List<string>>.ToString();;
   val it : string = "Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpList`1[T]"

   > typedefof<List<int>>.ToString();;
   val it : string = "Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpList`1[T]"

   > typedefof<List<_>>.ToString();;
   val it : string = "Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpList`1[T]"
   ```

By the way, the `Type` class has an instance method to `GetGenericTypeDefinition()`. That means, the following two return the same instance:

```
    > Object.ReferenceEquals(typeof<List<int>>.GetGenericTypeDefinition(), typedefof<List<int>>);;
    val it : bool = true
```

What happens if you call `typeof<List<_>>`? You get back the `Type` definition for `List<Object>`, as phoog mentioned.

```
> typeof<List<_>>.ToString();;
val it : string = "Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpList`1[System.Object]"
```

This is all helpful to understand. For example, suppose I need to know if an object is a generic list (of any type).

```
// does not give me the answer I naively expected
> o.GetType() = typeof<List<_>>;; 
val it : bool = false

// does this reference point to a List<'T>?
> o.GetType().IsGenericType && o.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() = typedefof<List<_>>;;
val it : bool = true
```

Additionally, if you want to late-bound instantiate a generic type, you can use the `MakeGenericType(...)` method which Aaron mentioned.

```
> let myList = typedefof<List<_>>.MakeGenericType(typeof<int>);;
val myList : Type = Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpList`1[System.Int32]
```